# Tensorflow Serving bazel build Error: mnist_inference_2.cc - Signatures' has not been declared

Tags: c++, c++11, tensorflow, mnist, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to replicate tensorflow serving examples from https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_advanced.html

But I get following error. It is possibly Tensorflow library error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    :

~/serving$ bazel build //tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_inference_2
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/serving/tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/BUILD:125:1: C++ compilation of rule '//tensorflow_serving/session_bundle:session_bundle' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -Wl,-z,-relro,-z,now -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer '-std=c++0x' -iquote . ... (remaining 103 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
In file included from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:30:0,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:40:22: error: 'Signatures' has not been declared
                      Signatures* signatures);
                      ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:43:28: error: 'Signatures' does not name a type
 Status SetSignatures(const Signatures& signatures,
                            ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:43:40: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'signatures' with no type [-fpermissive]
 Status SetSignatures(const Signatures& signatures,
                                        ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:51:5: error: 'ClassificationSignature' has not been declared
     ClassificationSignature* signature);
     ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:58:5: error: 'ClassificationSignature' has not been declared
     ClassificationSignature* signature);
     ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:64:31: error: 'RegressionSignature' has not been declared
                               RegressionSignature* signature);
                               ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:73:32: error: 'ClassificationSignature' does not name a type
 Status RunClassification(const ClassificationSignature& signature,
                                ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:73:57: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'signature' with no type [-fpermissive]
 Status RunClassification(const ClassificationSignature& signature,
                                                         ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:83:28: error: 'RegressionSignature' does not name a type
 Status RunRegression(const RegressionSignature& signature, const Tensor& input,
                            ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:83:49: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'signature' with no type [-fpermissive]
 Status RunRegression(const RegressionSignature& signature, const Tensor& input,
                                                 ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:90:28: error: 'GenericSignature' has not been declared
                            GenericSignature* signature);
                            ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:94:28: error: 'Signature' has not been declared
                            Signature* default_signature);
                            ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:100:26: error: 'Signature' has not been declared
                          Signature* default_signature);
                          ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:106:32: error: 'GenericSignature' does not name a type
 Status BindGenericInputs(const GenericSignature& signature,
                                ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:106:50: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'signature' with no type [-fpermissive]
 Status BindGenericInputs(const GenericSignature& signature,
                                                  ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:117:31: error: 'GenericSignature' does not name a type
 Status BindGenericNames(const GenericSignature& signature,
                               ^
./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/signature.h:117:49: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'signature' with no type [-fpermissive]
 Status BindGenericNames(const GenericSignature& signature,
                                                 ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:68:49: error: 'AssetFile' was not declared in this scope
                               const std::vector<AssetFile>& asset_files,
                                                 ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:68:49: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/manifest.pb.h:19:0,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:29,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/manifest.pb.h:237:7: note:   'tensorflow::contrib::AssetFile'
 class AssetFile : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
       ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:68:58: error: template argument 1 is invalid
                               const std::vector<AssetFile>& asset_files,
                                                          ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:68:58: error: template argument 2 is invalid
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc: In function 'void tensorflow::serving::{anonymous}::AddAssetsTensorsToInputs(tensorflow::StringPiece, const int&, std::vector<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor> >*)':
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:70:20: error: request for member 'empty' in 'asset_files', which is of non-class type 'const int'
   if (!asset_files.empty()) {
                    ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(const int&)'
     for (auto& asset : asset_files) {
                        ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/array:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:79,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:21,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> _Tp* std::begin(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24: note:   mismatched types '_Tp [_Nm]' and 'const int'
     for (auto& asset : asset_files) {
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/array:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:79,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:21,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:58:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&)
     begin(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:58:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&) [with _Container = int]':
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:58:5: error: request for member 'begin' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'const int'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:48:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&)
     begin(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:48:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&) [with _Container = const int]':
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:48:5: error: request for member 'begin' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'const int'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/utility:74:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:79,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:21,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/initializer_list:89:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::begin(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
     begin(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/initializer_list:89:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24: note:   mismatched types 'std::initializer_list<_Tp>' and 'int'
     for (auto& asset : asset_files) {
                        ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24: error: no matching function for call to 'end(const int&)'
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/array:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:79,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:21,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note: template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> _Tp* std::end(_Tp (&)[_Nm])
     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24: note:   mismatched types '_Tp [_Nm]' and 'const int'
     for (auto& asset : asset_files) {
                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/stdexcept:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/array:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:79,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:21,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&)
     end(const _Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&) [with _Container = int]':
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:78:5: error: request for member 'end' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'const int'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&)
     end(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.end())
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&) [with _Container = const int]':
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:68:5: error: request for member 'end' in '__cont', which is of non-class type 'const int'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/utility:74:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:79,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:21,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/initializer_list:99:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::end(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
     end(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/initializer_list:99:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:71:24: note:   mismatched types 'std::initializer_list<_Tp>' and 'int'
     for (auto& asset : asset_files) {
                        ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:76:69: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor> >::push_back(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
           {asset.tensor_binding().tensor_name(), assets_file_tensor});
                                                                     ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:76:69: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/vector:64:0,
                 from external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.h:43,
                 from external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/metadata.h:43,
                 from bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/lib/core/error_codes.pb.h:25,
                 from external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/lib/core/status.h:22,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:23,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:901:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor>]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:901:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor>&}'
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:919:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor>]
       push_back(value_type&& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:919:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor> >::value_type&& {aka std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, tensorflow::Tensor>&&}'
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc: At global scope:
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:103:39: error: 'AssetFile' was not declared in this scope
                     const std::vector<AssetFile>& asset_files,
                                       ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:103:39: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/manifest.pb.h:19:0,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:29,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/manifest.pb.h:237:7: note:   'tensorflow::contrib::AssetFile'
 class AssetFile : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
       ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:103:48: error: template argument 1 is invalid
                     const std::vector<AssetFile>& asset_files,
                                                ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:103:48: error: template argument 2 is invalid
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:117:36: error: 'AssetFile' was not declared in this scope
                  const std::vector<AssetFile>& asset_files,
                                    ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:117:36: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/manifest.pb.h:19:0,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:29,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/manifest.pb.h:237:7: note:   'tensorflow::contrib::AssetFile'
 class AssetFile : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
       ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:117:45: error: template argument 1 is invalid
                  const std::vector<AssetFile>& asset_files,
                                             ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:117:45: error: template argument 2 is invalid
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc: In function 'tensorflow::Status tensorflow::serving::LoadSessionBundleFromPath(const tensorflow::SessionOptions&, tensorflow::StringPiece, tensorflow::serving::SessionBundle*)':
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:165:15: error: 'AssetFile' was not declared in this scope
   std::vector<AssetFile> asset_files;
               ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:165:15: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/manifest.pb.h:19:0,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:29,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/manifest.pb.h:237:7: note:   'tensorflow::contrib::AssetFile'
 class AssetFile : public ::google::protobuf::Message {
       ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:165:24: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<AssetFile> asset_files;
                        ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:165:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:165:37: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
   std::vector<AssetFile> asset_files;
                                     ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:170:17: error: expected ';' before 'asset_file'
       AssetFile asset_file;
                 ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:171:25: error: the value of 'AssetFile' is not usable in a constant expression
       if (!any_asset.Is<AssetFile>()) {
                         ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:165:15: note: 'AssetFile' was not declared 'constexpr'
   std::vector<AssetFile> asset_files;
               ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:171:36: error: no matching function for call to 'google::protobuf::Any::Is() const'
       if (!any_asset.Is<AssetFile>()) {
                                    ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:171:36: note: candidate is:
In file included from bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/protobuf/meta_graph.pb.h:32:0,
                 from ./tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.h:25,
                 from tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:16:
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/any.pb.h:66:29: note: template<class T> bool google::protobuf::Any::Is() const
   template<typename T> bool Is() const {
                             ^
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/any.pb.h:66:29: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:174:13: error: 'asset_file' was not declared in this scope
             asset_file.descriptor()->full_name(), ". Got: ",
             ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:178:32: error: 'asset_file' was not declared in this scope
       if (!any_asset.UnpackTo(&asset_file)) {
                                ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:182:19: error: request for member 'push_back' in 'asset_files', which is of non-class type 'int'
       asset_files.push_back(asset_file);
                   ^
tensorflow_serving/session_bundle/session_bundle.cc:182:29: error: 'asset_file' was not declared in this scope
       asset_files.push_back(asset_file);
                             ^
Target //tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_inference_2 failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.822s, Critical Path: 4.54s
```

Comment: Why don't you ask on the project's mailing list? We're not their support service.

Comment: ufff...  In mailing list also, they say the same. Well, I do not treat any of you as support service, but an open forum to learn and share.

Comment: By "say the same", I meant, in mailing list, they ask to post in stackoverflow. Is this same guy torturing us!

Comment: Why would the authors of a library send you elsewhere for help with that library? That's extremely odd. It is most likely that they are simply being lazy.

Comment: Now-a-days I find most questions get such a reply. Recent;y one question has been posted with proof of no reply from stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

From the page you linked: "*Before getting started, please complete the [prerequisites](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/setup#prerequisites).*"

The type `Signatures` is defined in a header generated by following said prereqs process, so you've either not followed those steps or not followed them correctly – there's no way to tell which just from the compiler errors.

Comment: I will re-follow all the steps surely. BTW, the following 2 headers are missing in git repo of example folder in tensorflow_serving .                                     #include "tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_inference.grpc.pb.h"
#include "tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_inference.pb.h"